# Aprendiendo a usar firstElementChild

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Anteriormente he estado haciendo una tabla con Jquery, en cual se me han complicado, en mi código, quiero que al eliminar o agregar una fila, me indique el Numero de fila que hizo dicha función(agregar o eliminar), para eso la función de eliminar ya me lo indica, ya que me mostraron que con **firstElementChild** le dice que fila o filas se elimino.
Pero con mi función de agregar no me ha salido, les muestro mi codigo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 $('#bt_add').click(function() {
      
  var check = [];            
    $("#tabla").find('.selected').find('td').each(function(){
      if($.trim($(this).text()) === "")
        check.push($(this).attr('id'));
   ;
    });
  
      if(check.length === 0)
      
       agregar();
    else 
      alert('No puedo agregar mas de una fila, por favor llene los campos');;
      
   });
  
   $('#bt_del').click(function() {

    eliminar();
  
    
  });  
      
   $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
     eliminarTodasFilas();
     alert('Elimino todas las filas');
   });
   reordenar();

 });
 var cont = 0;
 var id_fila_selected = [];
 
 function agregar() {
   cont++;
   var fila =
   
     '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

     '<td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';


   $('#tabla').append(fila);
   reordenar();
   
 }

 
 function addToTable(e) {
  
  
   if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
     if($("#nombre").val() == ""){
       alert("Ingrese el nombre del usuario");
     return false;
      }else if($("#area").val() == ""){
       alert("Ingrese el nombre de la area");
      return false;
      }else if($("#puesto").val() == ""){
       alert("Ingrese el nombre del puesto");
      return false;
      }else if($("#email").val() == ""){
       alert("Ingrese su correo electronico");
      return false;
      
      }
     const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
     const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
     const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
     const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
     [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
      if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
       else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
      
     });
     
     reordenar();
     id_fila_selected=[];
   }
 }

 function seleccionar(id_fila) {
   if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
     $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
   
     var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila); 
     id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
   } else {
     $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
   
     id_fila_selected.push(id_fila); 
   }
  
 }
 
  function eliminar() {
   const ids = id_fila_selected.join();
   var dels = 0;
   var idfilas ="";
   for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
    idfilas += document.getElementById(id_fila_selected[i]).firstElementChild.textContent + "...";
    $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
    dels++;
   
   }
   
  if (dels==1)
   alert('Se ha eliminado la fila' + idfilas);
  else 
   alert('Se han eliminado las filas' + idfilas);
   reordenar();
   id_fila_selected=[];
   
   
  }
  
 

 function reordenar() {
   var num = 1;
   $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
     $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
     num++;
   });
 }

 function eliminarTodasFilas() {
   $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
     $(this).remove();
   });
 }
 
 $(function () {     
  
   $("table").on("dblclick", "td",function () {     
        var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
        
        $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
        $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
        
        $(this).children().first().focus();
        $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                var newContent = $(this).val();
                $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
              
            }
           
            });
        $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
           
            });
        
        
        });
    
    });
```

```css
#content{
  position: absolute;
  min-height: 50%;
  width: 80%;
  top: 20%;
  left: 5%;
 }

 .selected{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .selected:hover{
  background-color: #EBF5FB;
  
 }
 .seleccionada{
  background-color: #81D4FA;
  
 }
 
 table thead {
background-color: #7FB3D5;

}
```

```html
<div align="center" style="width:416px;" >
      <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
   <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
      <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar todo</button>
    </div>
      <table id="tabla" style= "position:absolute;top:150px;left:75px" class="table table-bordered">
         
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nº</th>
        <th>NOMBRE</th>
        <th>AREA</th>
        <th>PUESTO</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
```

Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Tu problema esque no peudes agragr otra fila, pro que te sale el alert?

Comment: @Hola, si me sale la fila y el alert pero no me indica que numero de fila que agregue, mas bien me indica su ID FILA, lo que me causa conflicto a futuro porque por ejemplo tengo dos filas en mi tabla y si borro una y luego quiero agregar otra me indicara "agrego la fila3" cuando es la fila numero 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Espero esto te sirva de algo :
Solo cambie tu contador para que contara los tr :**

```
var cont_fila = ($('#tabla tbody').find('tr').length) + 1;
```

```js
  

    $(document).ready(function() {
     
     $('#bt_add').click(function() {      
      var check = [];            
        $("#tabla").find('.selected').find('td').each(function(){
          if($.trim($(this).text()) === "")
            check.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
               
           agregar();
                
       });
      
       $('#bt_del').click(function() {
        eliminar();   
      });  
          
       $('#bt_delall').click(function() {
         eliminarTodasFilas();
         alert('Elimino todas las filas');
       });
       reordenar();   
     });
      
     var cont = 0;
     var id_fila_selected = [];
     
     function agregar() {
        var cont_fila = ($('#tabla tbody').find('tr').length) + 1;
       var fila =   
         '<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont_fila + '" onclick="seleccionar(this.id);"><td></td>' +
         '<td><input type="text" id="nombre"></td>' +

         '<td><input type="text" id="area"></td>' +

         '<td><input type="text" id="puesto"></td>' +

         '<td><input type="text" id="email" onkeyup="addToTable(event)"></td></tr>';

       $('#tabla').append(fila);
        alert("Agrego la fila :" + cont_fila)
       reordenar();
       
     }

     
     function addToTable(e) {  
      
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
      
         if($("#nombre").val() == ""){
           alert("Ingrese el nombre del usuario");
         return false;
          }else if($("#area").val() == ""){
           alert("Ingrese el nombre de la area");
          return false;
          }else if($("#puesto").val() == ""){
           alert("Ingrese el nombre del puesto");
          return false;
          }else if($("#email").val() == ""){
           alert("Ingrese su correo electronico");
          return false;
          
          }
         const row = e.target.parentNode.parentNode;
         const inputs = row.querySelectorAll('input');
         const values = [].map.call(inputs, input => input.value);
         const tds = row.querySelectorAll('td');
         [].forEach.call(tds, (td, i) => {
          if (i === 0) { td.textContent = i + 1; }
           else { td.innerHTML = values[i - 1]; }
          
         });
         
         reordenar();
         id_fila_selected=[];
       }
     }

     function seleccionar(id_fila) {
       if ($('#' + id_fila).hasClass('seleccionada')) {
         $('#' + id_fila).removeClass('seleccionada');
       
         var existe_el_id = id_fila_selected.indexOf(id_fila); 
         id_fila_selected.splice(existe_el_id, 1);
       } else {
         $('#' + id_fila).addClass('seleccionada');
       
         id_fila_selected.push(id_fila); 
       }
      
     }
     
      function eliminar() {
       const ids = id_fila_selected.join();
       var dels = 0;
       var idfilas ="";
       for (var i = 0; i < id_fila_selected.length; i++) {
        idfilas += document.getElementById(id_fila_selected[i]).firstElementChild.textContent + "...";
        $('#' + id_fila_selected[i]).remove();
        dels++;
       
       }
       
      if (dels==1)
       alert('Se ha eliminado la fila' + idfilas);
      else 
       alert('Se han eliminado las filas' + idfilas);
       reordenar();
       id_fila_selected=[];
       
       
      }
      
     

     function reordenar() {
       var num = 1;
       $('#tabla tbody tr').each(function() {
         $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(num);
         num++;
       });
     }

     function eliminarTodasFilas() {
       $('#tabla tr.selected').each(function() {
         $(this).remove();
       });
     }
     
     $(function () {     
      
       $("table").on("dblclick", "td",function () {     
var cont_fila = ($('#tabla tbody').find('tr').length);
alert("Usted esta editando la fila : " + cont_fila)
            var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
            
            $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
            $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + OriginalContent + "' />");
            
            $(this).children().first().focus();
            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var newContent = $(this).val();
                    $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                  
                }
               
                });
            $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
                $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
               
                });
            
            
            });
        
        });
```

```css
#content{
      position: absolute;
      min-height: 50%;
      width: 80%;
      top: 20%;
      left: 5%;
     }

     .selected{
      cursor: pointer;
     }
     .selected:hover{
      background-color: #EBF5FB;
      
     }
     .seleccionada{
      background-color: #81D4FA;
      
     }
     
     table thead {
    background-color: #7FB3D5;

    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div align="center" style="width:416px;" >
          <button id="bt_add" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
       <button id="bt_del" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar</button>
          <button id="bt_delall" class="btn btn-primary">Eliminar todo</button>
        </div>
          <table id="tabla" style= "position:absolute;top:150px;left:75px" class="table table-bordered">
             
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nº</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>AREA</th>
            <th>PUESTO</th>
            <th>EMAIL</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Wow gracias, solo una duda cual es la diferencia del **var cont_fila = ($('#tabla tbody').find('tr').length) + 1;**  con **cont++**

Comment: Cuentas los tr que hay en el momento (osea si tienes 3 y borras 1, te quedan 2 tr y el contaba los tr) y en el otro era un acumulativo osea si se quedo en 3 y borrastes 1 como es acumulativo se incrementa, POR OTRO LADO TUVE QUE SACAR TU RESTRICCION DE LENTH EN ESTA PARTE if(check.length === 0) :D, solo para probar

Comment: Es que en esa parte, cuenta las veces que se agrega una fila por que restringe que solo agregue una fila

Comment: Hola @IvanMoreFlores, otra duda, quiero poner ese mismo código en la parte: **$("table").on("dblclick", "td",function () {**
Solo que ya tiene la **var OriginalContent = $(this).text();** y cambiarlo por **var cont_mod = ($('#tabla tbody').find('tr').length)+1;** lo afectaría porque es la parte de editar una fila. ¿Se tienen que combinar estos dos códigos? o ¿existe otra forma?, espero que se entienda mi duda...

Comment: Con que fianlidad quieres hacer ese cambio'

Comment: Que haga lo mismo como en **agregar()** que me diga en que fila y  en que columna edite los datos.

Comment: Hola Ivan, a acabo de resolverlo,resulta que solo tenia que quitar **+1**, gracias!!